# Can one worship Lord Shiva after smoking weed?

Tags: shiva

I am immersed in devotion after smoking weed.  Can I worship Lord Shiva after smoking weed?  Or it will be worship of weed not Shiva?

Comment: At best, there are protocols that would surround such a ritual. Search for a Guru, they will guide you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Can I worship Lord Shiva after smoking weed? Or it will be worship of weed not Shiva?

Your question is about TRANSCENDENTAL MEDITATION through use of Drugs. In that case the answer of Hinduism (Ayurveda Perspective is no). Because using recreational drugs for meditation in limited quantity and under supervision of Guru , with complete control on desires and mind is recommended. But since the drugs like you mentioned are highly addictive , often there is risk of overusing them or their abuse which will possibly create  serious health problems.  Then our mind falsely will consider this euphoria created by drugs as TRANSCENDENTAL MEDITATION , which is called as **Pragya-Aparadha** .

---

From Ayurveda perspective term Pragya-Aparadha menas the **mind's error or mistake of the intellect.** And this  "Mind's error  or Mistake of the intellect " involves disobeying the laws of nature.
 There are three common mistakes listed in the on various sources are   Attachment (or addiction), desires (weak will power) and show off (ego).
Charaka Samhita a  Ayurvedic  book  defines Pragya-aparadh as the lack of coordination of dhi, dhriti and smriti. Pragya-aparadh is the source of all disease, because disease originates when the heart, mind or body loses its connection with nature's intelligence.

- dhi (learning)
- dhriti (retention)
- smriti (long-term memory)

Below is verse from [**Charaka Samhita - Sarirasthana - Chapter 2**](https://archive.org/stream/CarakaSamhitaEng.Vol.1/caraka-samhita_Eng.%20Vol.%201#page/n453/mode/2up)

> **प्रज्ञापराधो** विषमास्तथाsर्था हेतुस्तुतीय: परिणामकाल : |
>  सर्वामयानां त्रिविधा च शान्तिर्ज्ञानार्थकाला: समयोगयुक्ता ||
>     40||
>
> **Intellectual error** , unbalanced use of senses and consequence of time these three are the cause of all the disorders . Similarly the
>   remedy of all the disorders consist of the balance use of intellect
>   ,senses and time.

---

Here is excellent article related to the topic . See the section [**Marijuana and the Mistake of the Intellect**](http://www.mapi.com/blog/the-ayurvedic-view-of-marijuana.html)  - The Ayurvedic Source of Disease

> Pragya aparadh means “the mistaken intellect,” which becomes isolated
>   from the rest of the universe. It is considered in Ayurveda to be the
>   root cause of all disease and problems in life. Through the mistake of
>   the intellect, our physiology forgets its basis in the unmanifest,
>   unified state of pure consciousness. There are three key elements to
>   Pragya aparadh. All three features of this mistaken intellect are
>   caused and aggravated by continued recreational use of cannabis.
>
> Buddhi Vibrhramsh is the disturbed intellect. In this condition one
>   sees that which is harmful as useful. Dhriti Bhramsha is disturbed
>   self-control where one cannot be restrained from that which is asatmya
>   (unwholesome), or that which deranges the mind. Smriti Bhramsha is
>   disturbed memory, where the texts say that the Self (sattwa) is
>   covered by rajas and tamas. Ayurveda states that the ideal mind is
>   Sattwa, or purity. Intake of cannabis aggravates Rajas, as seen in the
>   increase of appetite and in long-term users’ aggression, and Tamas, as
>   seen in the dullness, tiredness, incoherent thinking and memory loss.
>   Using cannabis, from an Ayurvedic perspective, for something other
>   than what it is intended, in ways not prescribed or intended, causes
>   imbalance to manas, the mind. Note here that these features are
>   consistent with the loss of prefrontal cortex executive control over
>   thinking, feeling and behavior associated with cannabis use.
>   Increasing dysfunction in this brain region is a prime nexus for the
>   extraordinarily potent hold of addiction and why overcoming addiction
>   is so difficult.
>
> Cannabis use also interferes with ojas, the master biochemical which
>   promotes unity, immunity and balance on all levels of mind and body.
>   The physiology reflects ojas through its balanced self-referral
>   functioning. When ojas is imbalanced or obstructed, the result is
>   susceptibility to disease; incoherent thought, speech and action; an
>   inclination to laziness; somnolence; and increased sleep. Ojas is also
>   associated with sukra, or reproductive tissue. Recent research has
>   shown the immunosuppressive effects of cannabinoids, causing the
>   susceptibility of cannabis users to certain cancers and infections.
>   Modern research suggests that heavy marijuana use lowers men's
>   testosterone levels and sperm count and quality.
>
> As indicated, used as a recreational drug, cannabis is toxic. Smoking
>   is a delivery therapy for some herbs for a variety of conditions in
>   Ayurveda. It is not used in any Maharishi Ayurveda® treatments in the
>   US. Traditionally, this kind of delivery requires the strict
>   preparation of ingredients in precise formulations for very specific
>   conditions. If used at all, it is prescribed at specific times by
>   trained experts under careful expert guidance. It is further stated in
>   Ayurveda that if one smokes the wrong substance at the wrong time, it
>   will create disease. Mental Imbalance Research indicates that loss of
>   mental stability is one significant side effect from recreational
>   marijuana use. In Ayurveda, the Sanskrit term Unmaada means “a
>   profound impairment of judgement, perception and clarity.” and can
>   affect  mind, intellect, consciousness, memory, desire, manners,
>   behavior and conduct.

**Conclusion**- And since while in Intoxicated condition we are with disturbed intellect ,  disturbed self-control and  disturbed consciousness , its not generally  good to worship any  god in that state. Unless in some situations (like tantrik Upasana etc.)

**The name Shiva menas  the auspicious one , So we should not be in inauspicious condition while worshiping Lord Shiva.** The Sadhu's  , saints who used such techniques previously were already well knowledgeable and reached at top of spiritual progress , so for them its was different thing , **but for us general people  generally its not recommended.**